# F# Conditional Branch With Async

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have a method that conditionally calls an async task:

```
let processMsg (msg : SocketMessage) =
    task{
        //....
        //....
        let user =
            if msg.User.IsSpecified && (msg.User.Value :? IUser) then
                user.Value :?> IUser
            else
                //Compiler: This construct may only be used within a computation expression
                let! user' = rest.GetUserAsync(UserId, config.restOptions)
                user'
        //....
        //....
    }
```

The compiler is complaining that I have to be within a computation expression.  I thought I was.  The only way I could get it to work is to split it out into an async child method:

```
let getUserAsync (user : SocketUser) =
    task{
        if user.IsSpecified && (user.Value :? IUser) then
            return user.Value :?> IUser
        else
            let! user' =
                rest.GetUserAsync(UserId, config.restOptions)
            return (user' :> IUser)
    }
```

Now I have an additional async context just to handle a rare corner case.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inside of `let user = ...` is *not* a computation expression. The `let` itself is inside a computation expression, but whatever is inside it is not. So you can't use `let!` in there.

The way to do what you're trying to do is to turn that `let` into a `let!` and then make sure that its right-hand side is a `Task`:

```
    let! user =
        if msg.User.IsSpecified && (msg.User.Value :? IUser) then
            Task.FromResult(user.Value :?> IUser)
        else
            rest.GetUserAsync(UserId, config.restOptions)
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. You can't use `return` directly inside `let!`

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting return must be used within a comp exp.  If I take return off, I get all branches must return the same type (IUser vs Task<IUser>) with that.

Comment: Oops, I meant `Task.FromResult` of course. Updated.

Comment: Nice, dude.  Thanks!